# Сравнение возрастов и итоговая запись, в виде min, max, middle. В чем ошибка не могу понять?

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vasyaAge = 25;
        int katyaAge = 22;
        int mishaAge = 35;

        int min = -1;
        int middle = -1;
        int max = -1;

        if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge) {
            min = katyaAge;
        }

        if (vasyaAge <= katyaAge && vasyaAge <= mishaAge) {
            min = vasyaAge;
        }

        if (mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge <= katyaAge) {
            min = mishaAge;
        }

        if (vasyaAge <= mishaAge && vasyaAge >= katyaAge || vasyaAge >= mishaAge <= katyaAge) {
            middle = vasyaAge;
        }

        if (mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge =>katyaAge || mishaAge >= vasyaAge <= katyaAge)
        {
            middle = mishaAge;
        }

        if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge =>mishaAge || katyaAge >= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge)
        {
            middle = katyaAge;
        }

        if (mishaAge >= katyaAge && mishaAge >= vasyaAge) {
            max = mishaAge;
        }

        if (vasyaAge > mishaAge && vasyaAge > katyaAge) {
            max = vasyaAge;
        }

        if (katyaAge > mishaAge && katyaAge > vasyaAge) {
            max = katyaAge;
        }
    }
            System.out.println ("Младший возраст: " min );
            System.out.println ("Средний возраст: " middle );
            System.out.println ("Старший возраст: " max );
}
```

Comment: `=>` - вот этот значок что означает? А вот это выражение - `vasyaAge >= mishaAge <= katyaAge`?

Comment: Вот этот значок => означает, мою невнимательность. А это выражение vasyaAge >= mishaAge <= katyaAge означает , что я не знаю о чем я сам говорю и пишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдите десять отличий.

```js
function test() {
  var vasyaAge = 25;
  var katyaAge = 22;
  var mishaAge = 35;

  var min = -1;
  var middle = -1;
  var max = -1;

  if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge) {
    min = katyaAge;
  }

  if (vasyaAge <= katyaAge && vasyaAge <= mishaAge) {
    min = vasyaAge;
  }

  if (mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge <= katyaAge) {
    min = mishaAge;
  }

  if ((vasyaAge <= mishaAge && vasyaAge >= katyaAge) ||
      (vasyaAge >= mishaAge && vasyaAge <= katyaAge)) {
    middle = vasyaAge;
  }

  if ((mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge >= katyaAge) ||
      (mishaAge >= vasyaAge && mishaAge <= katyaAge)) {
    middle = mishaAge;
  }

  if ((katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge >= mishaAge) ||
      (katyaAge >= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge)) {
    middle = katyaAge;
  }

  if (mishaAge >= katyaAge && mishaAge >= vasyaAge) {
    max = mishaAge;
  }

  if (vasyaAge > mishaAge && vasyaAge > katyaAge) {
    max = vasyaAge;
  }

  if (katyaAge > mishaAge && katyaAge > vasyaAge) {
    max = katyaAge;
  }

  console.log("Младший возраст: ", min);
  console.log("Средний возраст: ", middle);
  console.log("Старший возраст: ", max);
}
test();
```

Comment: Отличия нашел, исправил ,спасибо! Но в месте где я делаю вывод информации, о минимальном, среднем и максимальном значении, System.out.println("Минимальный возраст:", min); строка подчеркивается, а в консоли выпадает ошибка Error:(41, 19) java: no suitable method found for println(java.lang.String,int)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length). С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: @KonstantinS Это связано с тем, что у метода `println` - один параметр: `System.out.println(String.format("Минимальный возраст: %d", min));`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String) Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @KonstantinS Это Вы стрелочку вверх нажали. Спасибо. Там чуть ниже еще есть "птичка", означающая "принятие" ответа.

Comment: Да как это работает???!!!! Почему именно "%d" позволяет нам вывести код без ошибки??? Поясните пожалуйста или укажите где именно посмотреть этот момент, я новичок в этом деле и я обескуражен!

Comment: @KonstantinS Это довольно обширная тема - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html. В данном случае - `%d` используется там, куда в строку должно быть вставлено целое число в десятичном виде.

Comment: Вы давно, знакомы с java? Я стопарюсь на простых задачах(как мне кажется) задачи подобной этой и каждый раз хочется все бросить, как это побороть, может посоветуете чего?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101768/discussion-between-konstantin-s-and-igor).

Answer (score 0):

```
      public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int vasyaAge = 13;
                int katyaAge = 18;
                int mishaAge = 45;
        
                int min = -1;
                int middle = -1;
                int max = -1;
        
                if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge) {
                    min = katyaAge;
                    if (vasyaAge > mishaAge){
                        max = vasyaAge;
                        middle = mishaAge;
                    }
                    else {
                        max = mishaAge;
                        middle = vasyaAge;
                    }
        
        
                }
                if (vasyaAge <= katyaAge && vasyaAge <= mishaAge) {
                    min = vasyaAge;
                    if (katyaAge > mishaAge){
                        max = katyaAge;
                        middle = mishaAge;
                    }
                    else {
                        max = mishaAge;
                        middle = katyaAge;
        
                    }
                }
                if (mishaAge <= katyaAge && mishaAge <= vasyaAge) {
                    min = mishaAge;
                    if (katyaAge > vasyaAge){
                        max = katyaAge;
                        middle = vasyaAge;
                    }
                    else {
                        max = mishaAge;
                        middle = katyaAge;
        
                    }
                }
        
                System.out.println("Младший возраст: " + min);
                System.out.println("Средний возраст: " + middle);
                System.out.println("Старший возраст: " + max);
        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vasyaAge = 25;
        int katyaAge = 22;
        int mishaAge = 35;
                                                                                                                    
        int min = -1;
        int middle = -1;
        int max = -1;
                                                                                                                    
        if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge) {
            min = katyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (vasyaAge <= katyaAge && vasyaAge <= mishaAge) {
            min = vasyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge <= katyaAge) {
            min = mishaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (vasyaAge <= mishaAge && vasyaAge >= katyaAge) {
            middle = vasyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (mishaAge <= vasyaAge && mishaAge >= katyaAge || mishaAge >= vasyaAge && vasyaAge <= katyaAge) {
            middle = mishaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (katyaAge <= vasyaAge && katyaAge >= mishaAge || katyaAge >= vasyaAge && katyaAge <= mishaAge) {
            middle = katyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (mishaAge >= katyaAge && mishaAge >= vasyaAge) {
            max = mishaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (vasyaAge > mishaAge && vasyaAge > katyaAge) {
            max = vasyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        if (katyaAge > mishaAge && katyaAge > vasyaAge) {
            max = katyaAge;
        }
                                                                                                                    
        System.out.println("??????? ???????: " + min);
        System.out.println("??????? ???????: " + middle);
        System.out.println("??????? ???????: " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]